# In Python, sys.path.append('path/to/module') throws syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to append the module path to my PYTHONPATH environment variable something like this

```
import sys
sys.path.append(0,"/path/to/module/abc.py")
```

I am getting syntax error

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Can anyone help me with correct syntax for `sys.path.append()` ?

Comment: The answers below a correct that you need `insert` instead of `append`, but the fact that you are getting a `SyntaxError` (not a `TypeError` means that you have a typo somewhere (unclosed parenthesis or something).

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are correct.

`append()` by default adds your argument to the *end* of the list. It's throwing a syntax error as you are passing it 2 arguments and it is only accepting 1.

Judging by your syntax you want your path added to the *front* of the path so `insert()` is the method to use.

You can read more in the documentation on [Data Structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> `list.append(x)`
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to
>   a[len(a):] = [x].
>
> `list.insert(i, x)`
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first
>   argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>   `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a),
>   x)` is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

```
import sys
# Inserts at the front of your path
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/module/abc.py")
# Inserts at the end of your path
sys.path.append('/path/to/module/abc.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use import sys sys.path.append(0,"/path/to/module/abc.py");

Just try:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/module/abc.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert it rather than append if you prefer:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/btilley/brads_py_modules")

import your_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have shown an example for help
Appending module to path.
paths is a list that has location of directories stored.

```
def _get_modules(self, paths, toplevel=True):
    """Take files from the command line even if they don't end with .py."""
    modules = []
    for path in paths:
        path = os.path.abspath(path)
        if toplevel and path.endswith('.pyc'):
            sys.exit('.pyc files are not supported: {0}'.format(path))
        if os.path.isfile(path) and (path.endswith('.py') or toplevel):
            modules.append(path)                        
        elif os.path.isdir(path):                       
            subpaths = [
                os.path.join(path, filename)
                for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path))]           
            modules.extend(self._get_modules(subpaths, toplevel=False))
        elif toplevel:
            sys.exit('Error: %s could not be found.' % path)
    return modules
```

Comment: Paths is a list that has the location of the directories.